# Master-Detail page with JSP

Tags: jsp

Hi
I need to create a Master-detail page with JSP, to add ,edit and delete details without form submission and I wondered if you could give some suggestions on how to achieve this (maybe a plugin).

Thanks in advance

Comment: With "without form submission" you probably actually mean "asynchronously with ajax"? Because it doesn't make sense to create a CRUD form without form submission. The server has got to know about the changes in some way, otherwise such a CRUD form would be pretty useless.

Comment: sorry, you're right. So, how do you usually handle this?

Answer (score 0):

... you may want to look at one of the JavaScript frameworks to help you with that unless you want get your hands dirty and want to roll the functionality from scratch. I'm biased toward jQuery for those things.